# Howto implement table / -detail with customizable javascript-code in the detail with Webcomponents

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm not a particular clever frontend-dev but i need to maintain and enhance two webcomponents which are used to show a [table](https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop/blob/master/src/cryptoadvance/specter/templates/includes/tx-table.html) and [rows](https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop/blob/master/src/cryptoadvance/specter/templates/includes/tx-row.html) in that table.

It worked fine so far. The table-element is querying a json-api on the server-side and it's creating `<tx-row>` elements on the fly like:

```
for (let tx of txlist) {
       let txRow = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
         <tx-row
          data-price="${this.price ? this.price : 0}"
          // many more attributes here
         </tx-row>
       `)
       this.tbody.append(txRow);
       // ...
}
```

So now i want to adjust that and make it reusable. In my case i want to add an optional first column where each row gets a checkbox which should call some javascript code.

If this would only be one component, slots would probably already solved my issue. However here i would need to somehow pass the slot further down in the `tx-row` and it doesn't sound like rocket-science but rather something very simple but i can't figure it out.

If this is easy if i would use `XYZ-framework`, i really hope that this framework is pretty slim. You know ... frontend-developmenet doesn't look to me as it would have evolved much from the state of [2016](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f).

But nevertheless, any hint highly appreciated! E.g. if anyone can point to a place where something similiar is solved already.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want an enhancement to the Specter-Desktop software you link to. They have a very active issues list. Aks for a feature there. -- I looked at their ``<tx-row>`` component, at line 20 it is just your regular TR HTML tag, so an extra column is another TD... no rocket science there if you change the **source code**.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of that project. Adding an extra-column is obviously not rocket-science, however, specifying call-back methods seem to be. 
A solution would be to use conventions (this component will call a function `updateCoinSelect` if the status of a checkbox changes. But i don't think that this is a very good design.

Comment: For loose coupling use Events instead of callbacks

Comment: Thank you, using events solved it here.